# Deduplicating IDs with Hive QL / Impala / Python

Tags: python, sql, hive, duplicates, impala

I need help deduplicating a list of users (20 million+) across a different set of IDs.

Here's how it looks like :
 - We have 3 kinds of userIDs : ID1, ID2 and ID3.
 - At least 2 of them are always sent together : ID1 with ID2 or ID2 with ID3. ID3 is never sent with ID1.
 - Users can have several ID1, ID2 or ID3.
 - So sometimes, in my table, I will have several lines with lots of different IDs, but it's possible that all of those can describe one single user.

An example :
[image]

All those IDs show one single user.

I'm thinking I could add a fourthID (GroupID), that would be the one deduplicating them. A bit like this :

[image]

Problem is : I know how to do this on SQL Server through the CURSOR / OPEN / FETCH / NEXT commands, but I only have Hive QL, Impala and Python available on my environment.

Would anyone know what would be the best way to approach this ?

Thanks a million times,

Hugo

Comment: Please provide your CURSOR / OPEN / FETCH / NEXT approach

Comment: Is id2 always exist (not null)?

Comment: Hi ! 
- ID2 always exists,  ID1 and ID3 can be null, but not null at the same time<br/>
- As for the cursor, I create a 4th column "GroupId" = ISNULL(ID1,ID3), and order the table by ID1 then GroupID.<br/>
Then I run the cursor to compare ID1 from one line to another, if it's the same, then GroupID = previousGroupID. If not, leave unchanged.<br/>
Then I run the cursor on the new output, ordered by ID2 and GroupID,and this time compare ID2 from one line to another. If ID2 = previousID2 THEN GroupID2 = previousGroupID, if not leave unchanged.<br/>
GroupID2 is my final deduplicated ID.<br/>

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, supposing id2 always exist, you can aggregate rows, group by id2:

```
select max(id1) id1,  id2, max(id3) id3 from
( --your dataset as in example
 select 'A'  as id1, 1 as id2,  null   as id3 union all
 select null as id1, 1 as id2, 'Alpha' as id3 union all
 select null as id1, 2 as id2, 'Beta'  as id3 union all
 select 'A'  as id1, 2 as id2,  null   as id3
 )s
 group by id2;

OK
A       1       Alpha
A       2       Beta
Time taken: 58.739 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

And now I'm trying to implement your logic as you described:

```
select --pass2
 id1, id2, id3,
 case when lag(id2) over (order by id2, GroupId) = id2 then lag(GroupId) over (order by id2, GroupId) else GroupId end GroupId2
 from
 (
 select        --pass1
 id1, id2, id3,
 case when 
 lag(id1) over(order by id1, NVL(ID1,ID3)) =id1 then lag(NVL(ID1,ID3))  over(order by id1, NVL(ID1,ID3)) else NVL(ID1,ID3) end GroupId
 from
( --your dataset as in example
 select 'A'  as id1, 1 as id2,  null   as id3 union all
 select null as id1, 1 as id2, 'Alpha' as id3 union all
 select null as id1, 2 as id2, 'Beta'  as id3 union all
 select 'A'  as id1, 2 as id2,  null   as id3
 )s
 )s --pass1
;


OK
id1     id2     id3     groupid2
A       1       NULL    A
NULL    1       Alpha   A
A       2       NULL    A
NULL    2       Beta    A
Time taken: 106.944 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your script ! It does work for that example indeed, but I just found out it won't in some cases, like if ID1 and ID2 have 3 times the same value, and ID3 has one that differs 3 times.
The problem will be that an offset will be created on each and every LAG()OVER(). In this example, on the 3rd row, the final groupID will not copy the last groupId :/

Comment: @HugoP. please provide data example then